# Can i install a custom utils.py module in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, conda, environment

I have made a custom utils.py file that needs to used with my feature extraction file. I will import from the utils file. How can i do it in conda environemnt

Comment: just keep this file in the same project directory, and then you can use `import utils` or `from utils import *` . Check this out for a more detailed guide: https://stackabuse.com/creating-and-importing-modules-in-python

Comment: what do u mean by project directory ? where conda is installed or where i have kept my codes ?

Comment: where you have kept your code.

Comment: conda is installed in a separate hdd partition while i kept my codes in desktop(ssd)